# React dates-Datepicker does not filter in ag-grid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I was trying to implement a custom Date filter in ag grid using React. The link I followed is [a link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-date-component/)!

I was able to create the component (SingleDatePicker) and able to render it on the cell. But I had tried a lot to make it filter the data with the selected date. It does not happen to filter. I have used the methods according to the documentation like updateAndNotifyAgGrid etc. but still no luck.

I am using the agDateColumnFilter and my own custom component for rendering.

Could anyone please help me point out where I am doing wrong for this to not filter the data.

Comment: updateAndNotifyAgGrid = date2 => {
  this.setState({date2});

    this.props.onDateChanged;
}

you should call this.props.onDateChanged();

Comment: It shows eror in console - "Uncaught TypeError: date.format is not a function"

Comment: Try moment(date).format

Comment: Are you able to create Sandbox or Plunker example of what you are facing so that others can look at your live code and make tweaks to see what's breaking or not working.